# how to limit bandwidth usage for mongodb master-slave sync

Tags: mongodb, bandwidth-throttling

Is there a way to limit bandwidth usage for mongodb master-slave sync.

The problem we've got is running out bandwidth when turn on mongodb master-slave sync.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding, even if you get low(ish) latency like < 10 ms, that can impact on your queries depending on the type of data load you have.

Also you end adding another point of failure to your system, communication between your application servers and database servers may fail. MongoDB doesn't use any encryption on it's protocol and your data will be running clear between many hops unless you tunnel it some way. And, as you pointed, there's the bandwidth use.

Overall I suggest you to get another node to run your DB, but at the same network of your application server.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to limit bandwidth usage for mongodb master-slave sync.

Not really, data is replicated via the oplog which is just a collection in the primary. So the secondary is effectively reading from the primary and pulling down data.

There's no compression available within MongoDB.

From a bandwidth persepective assume that everything going to the primary is going to the secondary as well. Your network hardware will need to be able to handle this traffic.